# Understanding python regexp

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have the following string:

```
out = "someUndefinedGarbageVALUE: 12 34 23 00possiblySomeOtherGarbage"
```

Now I want to parse the "12 34 23 00" value. In this case I perform the following:

```
regex = re.compile('VALUE: (\d\d\s?)*')
matches = regex.findall(out)
```

However in such case I will only get:

```
00
```

When I upgrage the regex a little:

```
regex = re.compile('VALUE: ((\d\d\s?)*)')
```

I will get:

```
12 34 23 00, 00
```

My questions:

1) With http://regexpal.com/ I see the first expression works nicely. Try for yourself:

```
VALUE: (\d\d\s?)*
```

against

```
garbageVALUE: 05 03 04garbage
```

With Python it is diffirent. Where is my reasoning wrong?

2) Why does the second expression catch exactly two groups? Should it catch only one

```
12 34 23 00
```

or all the possible variations?

```
12, 12\s, 12\s34 ...
```

I understand that this is a greedy search, but why exactly two groups are caught?

Comment: How are you trying to look at the match? For the first regex, doing a `regex.search(out).group()` returns `'VALUE: 12 34 23 00'`. What do you expect to get?

Comment: In Python you're looking at the match for the first capture group. `regexpal.com` is showing the match for the entire regexp. When you quantify a capture group, it only captures the last match.

Comment: Try three examples on your screen `>>> re.findall("aab", 'aabaabaabaa')`, `re.findall("a(a)(b)", 'aabaabaabaa')`, `>>>  re.findall("a(a)b", 'aabaabaabaa')` and now change your regex to `r"(VALUE: (\d\d\s?)*)"` you will understand - remember when you add `(` `)`  in regex you have some [`groups`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.groups) in output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is caused by [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). From the docs:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

This explains why you get `00`: That's what the group `(\d\d\s?)` matched last.

And:

> this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group

`((\d\d\s?)*)` contains two groups, so `findall` returns `('12 34 23 00', '00')`.

---

You can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead.

```
>>> print [match.group() for match in re.finditer('VALUE: (\d\d\s?)*', out)]
['VALUE: 12 34 23 00']
```